# Facebook Sharing url link showing improper thumbnail image on facebook pop-up window

Tags: wordpress, facebook

i added sharing feature in my blog,but when i click to share the blog in facebook. in the pop-up-window showing improper image. but in facebook it showing correct image... 
[image]

i don't know the Technical issues
url of my blog: http://www.codingexpertz.in/mclaren-and-honda-unveil-2015-f1-car/

Answer (score 1):

Have you used this meta tag?

```
<meta property="og:image"content="YOUR-IMAGE-URL" />
```

The wrong image can be a result of the Facebook cache. You can test it using [Facebook's debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at your web page in the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codingexpertz.in%2Fmclaren-and-honda-unveil-2015-f1-car%2F), you don't have any [open graph metadata](http://ogp.me/) on your page.

There are several plugins that will add this metadata for you. My personal favorite is [Wordpress SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/)